# MinGW and Eclipse on Windows - generating assembly output

Tags: c, eclipse, assembly, mingw

I recently installed MinGW to play around with (non-AVR-specific) C development on Windows.  I'd like to see the assembly generated by GCC along with the .o file; I've played around with changing some of the command line flags under "C/C++ build" and "Properties" for the test project I'm using, but I can't seem to alter the build behavior.  Is there a straightforward way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The way to do it is to add `-Wa,-aln=output.s` to the "Command" box under Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > GCC C Compiler.

Answer (score 1):

[Bitrex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696226/mingw-and-eclipse-on-windows-generating-assembly-output/10697544#10697544) was on the right path but a better way to do is under "Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > GCC C Compiler > Miscellaneous", append `-Wa,-aln='${CWD}\\${InputFileBaseName}.cod'` (take notice of the single quotes) to the end of "Other flags". This will not only generate the assembly, but seperate them by the source file.
With [Bitrex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696226/mingw-and-eclipse-on-windows-generating-assembly-output/10697544#10697544)'s way, if you have multiple source files, each assembly output will be overwritten by the next source file, because he forces them all to be named "output.s".
**Note**: Use "GCC C++ Compiler" if your compiling C++ code.